# scipy minimization with more complex marketing function

Tags: optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

I am new to scipy minimize. I want to minimize a function. There are 2 vectors in play :

x : 4 element vector of spending

y : 4 element vector of cost per customer

each element in y is defined something like 50 from 0 to 100000, and 0.0005 * X from 100000 to infinity

The objective function is to minimize the spend :

```
def objective(x):
    x1=x[0]
    x2=x[1]
    x3=x[2]
    x4=x[3]
    return x1+x2+x3+x4
```

As the constraint I have the number of users I have to sign up for like this :

```
def constraint1(x,y):
    x[0]/y[0]+x[1]/y[1]+x[2]/y[2]+x[3]/y[3]>5035
```

bounds and definition like this

```
b=(0,1000000)
bnds=(b,b,b,b)
con1={'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint1}
x0=[20000,20000,20000,20000]
sol= minimize(objective,x0, method= "SLSQP",bounds=bnds,constraints=con1)
```

I simply do not know to define the Y vector properly. Any feedback or help wound be very much appreciated .

Comment: The variables need to be organized in one big array `X=(x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4)`. See the documentation and examples.

Comment: I seem to not be able to find examples for that. I am also a bit confused why you would say that y is a variable. since it is a set of functions. Could you please explain it further to a beginner :)

Comment: Usually in math x and y are variables. I have never seen a text where y is something else.

Comment: You are right, I did not phrase this well. Could you still give me a hint how to do it ?